# Multiple declarations of template struct, used for getting enum, describing the template type

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I'm having the following enumerator:

```
enum class VariableType
{
    Basic,
    Vector2,
    Vector3,
    Vector4
};
```

and 3 vector class template: Vector2, Vector3 and Vector4.

I'm looking for a function used to initialize VariableType variables with, by passing the data type in the template parameter.

For example:

```
auto type1 = GetVariableType<float>::type; // type1 = VariableType::Basic
auto type2 = GetVariableType<Vector2<float> >::type; // type1 = VariableType::Vector2
```

I came up with the idea to define GetVariableType twice, with different templates, but the code is not compiling when I'm writing the second definition( std::enable_if_t::value>).

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<IsBasicType<T>::value>>
struct GetVariableType
{
    static const VariableType type = VariableType::Basic;
};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<IsVector2Type<T>::value>>
struct GetVariableType
{
    static const VariableType type = VariableType::Vector2;
};
```

Any ideas how I'm supposed to distinguish the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but seems to me that you're looking something as

```
template<typename T>
struct GetVariableType
 { static constexpr VariableType type = VariableType::Basic; };

template<typename T>
struct GetVariableType<Vector2<T>>
 { static constexpr VariableType type = VariableType::Vector2; };

template<typename T>
struct GetVariableType<Vector3<T>>
 { static constexpr VariableType type = VariableType::Vector3; };

template<typename T>
struct GetVariableType<Vector4<T>>
 { static constexpr VariableType type = VariableType::Vector4; };
```

simply using template specialization.

Off Topic suggestion: avoid the name `type` for a variable.

In the type-traits standard library, the identifier `type` is usually used to define (through a `using` or a `typedef`) a type, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with variables (as the name of your template implies) instead of types, then you can do:

```
template<typename T> VariableType GetVariableType (T) {return VariableType::Basic; };
template<typename T> VariableType GetVariableType (Vector2 <T>) { return VariableType::Vector2; };
template<typename T> VariableType GetVariableType (Vector3 <T>) { return VariableType::Vector3; };
template<typename T> VariableType GetVariableType (Vector4 <T>) { return VariableType::Vector4; };
```

And then you can do (for example):

```
float f = 0;
auto type1 = GetVariableType (f);
std::cout << (int) type1 << '\n';

Vector2 <float> v2;
auto type2 = GetVariableType (v2);
std::cout << (int) type2 << '\n';
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/r9ijTu8BIMPoUn6J)